# Unit testing Couchdb model in Pylons

Tags: unit-testing, pylons, couchdb

Given a default pylons installation are there any examples available on the best practices for unit testing a CouchDB model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to interact with CouchDB?  Are you using [couchdb-python](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/)?

In any case, you would probably follow many of the conventions related to using something like [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) along with [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.1/).

I would take a look at [couchdb-python's tests](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/tests/couch_tests.py) as a good starting point.